# Why can't I pass a shared pointer of ULARGE_INTEGER, but a ULARGE_INTEGER* without problems?

Tags: c++, pointers

Here is my problem:

```
std::shared_ptr<ULARGE_INTEGER> freeBytesAvailable = std::shared_ptr<ULARGE_INTEGER>(new ULARGE_INTEGER);
std::shared_ptr<ULARGE_INTEGER> totalNumberOfBytes = std::shared_ptr<ULARGE_INTEGER>(new ULARGE_INTEGER);
std::shared_ptr<ULARGE_INTEGER> totalNumberOfFreeBytes = std::shared_ptr<ULARGE_INTEGER>(new ULARGE_INTEGER);

ULARGE_INTEGER *test = new ULARGE_INTEGER;
ULARGE_INTEGER *test2 = new ULARGE_INTEGER;
ULARGE_INTEGER *test3 = new ULARGE_INTEGER;

if (GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(NULL, test3, test2, test))
{
    //do something
}
```

as you can see, I want to call GetDiskFreeSpaceEx, and as a parameter it expects a `PULARGE_INTEGER`, so a pointer to a `ULARGE_INTEGER`

If I am using test, test2 and test3 as parameter it works totally fine.
However, I want to learn about smart pointers and therefor try to include some in my code and use them.

Everytime I try to pass my smart pointers, I get a conversion error, so something has to be wrong with the data type, but I just can't figure out the problem.

Shouldn't both be pointing to a ULARGE_INTEGER?

Can someone help? My guess would be that I would have to kind of unpack the raw pointer out of the smart pointer wrapper, but I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: When in doubt start with a [good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shared pointers are really just objects encapsulating raw pointers. Hence, you can pass shared pointers as function parameters only if the called function accepts a shared pointer as a parameter! You cannot pass a raw pointer in lieu of a shared pointer and vice versa. However, there are instances where you may want to pass the underlying raw pointer as an argument to a function call. This is typically the case when you have to make a C- library call. In such cases, just extract the underlying raw pointer using the `get()` method on the shared pointer object.
So in your case, the call to `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` should be:

```
GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(NULL,freeBytesAvailable.get(), totalNumberOfBytes.get(), totalNumberOfFreeBytes.get() )
```

that is assuming that the function takes these parameters in this order.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, so I will write it down for anyone looking for a quick solution as well:

```
.get()
```

will return the raw pointer, so if you are trying to pass a smart pointer to a function expecting a pointer, just add it and you are good to go.